# Am I using _mm_srl_epi32 wrong?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, sse, simd

In this small code example:

```
__m128i twos = _mm_set_epi32(2,3,1,2);
__m128i foo = _mm_set_epi32(128,128,128,128);
__m128i shifted = _mm_srl_epi32(foo,twos);
```

"shifted" is full of zeroes, while I expect it two be full of four 32-bit integers with the values 32,16,64, and 32, respectively. Am I using the intrinsic wrong?

Comment: If you want element-wise shift, you need either AMD's XOP or Intel's AVX2 instructions.

Comment: @Mysticial I wonder... I've encountered this quite a lot of times now that certain things you might expect SIMD to do weren't available in the early SSE versions (some aren't available even now), such as simple 4 element multiplications for 32 bit elements which only became available with SSE 4.1. I wonder if this was simply a factor of cost (too expensive to integrate SIMD ALUs into cpu)... surely they must have though of this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are using it incorrectly. The second argument to `_mm_srl_epi32()` specifies the amount of bits to shift the first argument by, but it isn't a vectored argument as you might expect, allowing you to shift each 32-bit integer by a different number of bits. Instead, the 128-bit argument is truncated to 64 bits, and the resulting count is used to determine the number of bits to shift; the same shift amount is used for all 4 integers in the first argument. In your case, the lower 64 bits are `0x0000000100000010`, which evaluates to a very large positive number. This results in all of the elements of `foo` getting flushed to zero as all of the bits are shifted out.

A good place to find all of the little details on every instruction out there is Intel's [AVX Programmer's Reference](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/c/6/7/c/4/17976-intel-avx-programming-reference-31943302.pdf). While the title may be somewhat of a misnomer, the document contains descriptions of all SSE/SSE2/.../AVX/AVX2 instructions and descriptions of their intrinsics available in Intel's C++ compiler (which are typically also available in `gcc` and others). Searching for `_mm_srl_epi32` in the document yields a clear explanation on exactly what the instruction does.